# What is Matrix representation of Lagrange's identity?

Tags: calculus, matrices

What is [Lagrange's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_identity) in terms of matrix?

Comment: It is a particular case of [the Binet-Cauchy identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity), which in turn is a particular case of [the Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) for determinants of matrix products. This is also explained in Example 6.39 of [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 10 January 2019](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Classroom note: An extension of Lagrange's identity to matrices](https://www.learntechlib.org/p/165727/) by Götz Trenkler, which should answer your question.

Comment: I took another link. You can google for alternatives, or go to the library.

Comment: do you have any book recommendation in that case